# Decimal numbers only textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have following jQuery function to make textbox accepting only decimal number, but problem is it didn't accept `.` , so it works as only integer textbox,

I don't want to use any plugin

here is the jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textbox1").keydown(function(event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 ||
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true))
        {
            return;
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 46)
        {
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && 
                (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 ))
            {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }        
    });
});​
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/VKrLx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#textbox1").keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;

    // backspace, tab, left arrow, up arrow, right arrow, down arrow, delete, numpad decimal pt, period, enter
    if (key != 8 && key != 9 && key != 37 && key != 38 && key != 39 && key != 40 && key != 46 && key != 110 && key != 190 && key != 13){
        if (key < 48){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (key > 57 && key < 96){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (key > 105) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

and what about `4.5.2` ?

your code is not checking it  !

`why` not using regex ?

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

just check the match when `blur` `event`